# Trying to write a Powershell query that shows all resource groups and the tag values

Tags: azure, powershell, tags

I am trying to use Powershell to create a csv file that will provide a list of the Resource Groups and the Value of the Tags I have associated with them called "Cost Code" and "Environment"

I have tried the following commands which a mixture of the two provide the information I need I just need to join the two outputs.

```
(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where ResourceGroupName -like rg*).Tags

(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where ResourceGroupName -like rg*) | select ResourceGroupName, Tags | ft
```

The way I would like it to look is

> ```
> ResourceGroup,Cost Code,Environment
> RG1,1,Dev
> RG2,2,Test
> RG3,3,Prod
> RG4,4,Dev
> RG5,5,Test
> RG6,6,Prod
> RG7,7,Dev
> RG8,8,Test
> RG9,9,Prod
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should output what you need:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -like "rg*"} |
        Select-Object @{n='ResourceGroup';e={$_.ResourceGroupName}},
                      @{n='Cost Code';e={$_.Tags['Cost Code']}},
                      @{n='Environment';e={$_.Tags['Environment']}} | 
            ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Explanation:**

`Select-Object` here is using calculated properties with three different hash tables. `ResourceGroup` is calculated only because you didn't specifically want the `ResourceGroupName` property provided by the standard output. Since `.Tags` stores a hash table, you can reference its values by named index (`hashtable['tag_name']`). The `Select-Object` results can be piped into any Object to CSV converter for the desired output. Here `ConvertTo-Csv` is used.

Comment: Thank you again for providing me with a great answer. This is a bit of a pet project I am working on and your help is really appreciated.